# How to display Chinese characters in an URL?

Tags: xetex, urls, cjk, xecjk

Here is a near minimal working example. I added Chinese text to show it works outside URLs.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load packages 
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{url}

% Begin the document
\begin{document}

這樣可以寫中文！

\url{https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/钱谦益.#.E8.BF.8E.E5.A8.B6.E6.9F.B3.E5.A6.82.E6.98.AF}

\end{document}
```

How to remedy the problem that the Chinese characters in the URL aren't displayed? The output is this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need as url font a font that contains all the glyphs used in your url. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\usepackage{url}

\newfontfamily\urlfontfamily{FandolSong-Regular}
\def\UrlFont{\urlfontfamily}

\begin{document}

這樣可以寫中文！ 


\url{https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/钱谦益.#.E8.BF.8E.E5.A8.B6.E6.9F.B3.E5.A6.82.E6.98.AF}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It took some time to get the typesetter on the iPad to learn new fonts, but it's the correct answer!